# Conda installation python shortcut

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda using the CLI.

It has modified my ~/.bash_profile as follow:

```
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/Solal/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/Solal/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/Solal/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/Solal/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

And the installation created a file `.bash_profile-anaconda3.bak` as follow: 
`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${PATH}`

I don't understand when I try to run python command it sills use MacOS default python version

which python returns: 
`/usr/bin/python`

How can I make my anaconda python the default one?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you sourced your .bashrc or .bashrc_profile files after making the changes?. Also, check on the terminal whether >>echo $PATH shows the PATH of your conda installation.

Comment: Thanks @Sameeresque I have now run `source ~/.bash_profile` and it launchs python from Anaconda.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source your `./bash_profile` after you have done the necessary modifications. Doing so executes the content of the file passed as the argument.

At the terminal:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Thanks I have done so :) Is there any way to keep this by default, so each time I open my terminal I don't have to run this command?

Comment: You will find this [SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) helpful